# Normal map causes flat shading

Tags: normal-map

Does anybody know why i get this flat-shading when i add a normal map even though i enabled smooth-shading? the moment i remove the normal map it goes back to smooth.

[image]

Thanks for the help! :)

[image]

Comment: That's curious. Try to set your "image texture" node to "non color data". hope it helps. cheers :)

Comment: Try selecting your Normal Map in the UV Editor to see how things are arranged. Your Normal Map has a lot of straight lines in it that may be causing the "Lines" on your barrel (Not the shading). Also the Image Texture Node for you Normal Map should be set to Non Color Data.

Comment: It might help if you upload you .blend file by using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Be sure to "Pack" the Normal Map into the file.

Comment: for sure, check if all faces are set too smooth shading. If you using pie menu, is very easy randomly set selected faces to flat pressing TAB and move mouse to right-down direction.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts so far. i added the blend-file and hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, as many people suggested, the Image node for the normal map was not set to non-color data:
[image]

Comment: Great, many thanks to you and the other users!

Comment: If you stumble upon this in Blender 2.8 then you may also touch the "Strenght:" Parameter in the Nodes.... Drove me crazy that the "Non Color" Option did nothing but then I touched Strenght and woooosh... Also made the rendering much better (no banding in Normal mapped faces)