# Smooth shading faceted when using bump/normal

Tags: shaders, faces, normal-map

I noticed smooth round surfaces get faceted when I apply normal/bump map onto them, without normal/bump they are smooth. Does any one have a solution for this besides increasing subdivision?
 1. Smooth shading no normal/bump map
 2. Flat shading
 3. Smooth shading with normal/bump map with flat look
 4. material setup

[image: Smooth shading without normal/bump map]
[image: Flat Shading]
[image: Smooth shading with normal/bump map, looks like a mix of flat and smooth shading]
[image: Material node]

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem in version 2.92.0 and was able to solve it by reducing the *Strength* parameter in the Bump node.

There are also answers in: [Normal map causes flat shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91042/normal-map-causes-flat-shading?rq=1)