# weird polygon lines when using bump map

Tags: bump

[image][image]
Hello, I'm having an issue where the lines in my mesh appear after I add a bump map. I'm using a bump map on other meshes in the scene but this is the only one with a problem. it only appears in the render view. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! You need to provide more details about your shader setup. Can you also share your file? https://blend-exchange.com. Maybe this helps? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91042/normal-map-causes-flat-shading There is also a known bug that could have caused this problem but I can't find the thread. Also see bug report https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/74367

Comment: Hi there! I've posted my shader setup! changing it to non colour doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: ben : Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately, it could well be the known issue which @HarryMcKenzie refers to, in which case we won't be able to help; your best route might be further subdivision of the mesh. Which isn't ideal.

Comment: dang, oh well. thanks heaps for your help, at least it's not all that noticeable.